# Performance of set vs arrays vs linked list in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

i am trying to study the difference between sets , arrays and linked lists in Java in terms of performace so the example i am working on is
if we need to see the common objects between two arrays , two set and two linked list , 
in the arrays we apply the for loop and compare , in set we use interscet or union?
but there is a huge difference in timing, any ideas?

Comment: Why did you tag C++ if the question is about Java? Have you tried to measure the execution time of various structures in various scenarios to get an idea of the answer?

Comment: What about some example code?

Comment: @assylias: I could imagine that the op wants to compare the results to the same tests written in C++. But he should have included that into his question, if so.

Comment: Anyway, there is nothing Java-specific in this question. Data structures are what they are in all languagues.

Comment: i thought of data strutcure not specific langugae  even Objective C works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between intersecting sets and intersecting lists or arrays.
When you intersect two sets, you need to iterate over one of them, and see if there is a corresponding member in the other set. Retrieval time for set is O(1), so the intersection is O(n).
When intersecting a list or an array, the intersection is O(n^2), since for each member in one list/array, you need to iterate over the whole other list/array

Comment: Retrieval time for set is O(1) -- I disagree. You must specify _which_ set you are using. Hash-set? Correct. Tree-set? not a chance.

Comment: Not even, I have no idea where people learn and sticks forever that Hashes offer O(1) lookup. It is not true! unless you have a perfect hash read an array, you will always get collitions and do linear search over the collitioned elements of one hash bucket! Hash does NOT translate into constant time!!!

Comment: the only way to have guaranteed intersection in linear time is by sorting both sets and iterating both simultaneously which is linear, check how it is done in STL <algorithm> set_intersection.

Comment: Java does not offer this and you have to implement it yourself, perhaps Apache CollectionUtils offers this ...

Comment: @GiovanniAzua, just because you have collisions doesn't mean it's not O(1). If I have to search through a bucket of 5 elements when my hashtable contains 1000 elements, it's still O(1).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you prepare a test bed for **microbenchmarking** so you can see the differences in timing. Be sure to run at least 10 repetitions and take warm ups outside of the measurements. Then compute means and standard deviations. If I remember correctly there is a nifty google project that offers this.

The first thing that should be clear to you is the asymptotic complexity or big O. If for instance you want to do a set intersect the best way would be.

```
 SortedSet<String> set1 = new TreeSet<String>(); // and populate
 SortedSet<String> set2 = new TreeSet<String>(); // and populate
 // intersect of two sorted sets can be done in linear time
```

This above is O(n) whereas all the other choices you mentioned are O(n^2) read worse complexity and slower.

Comment: `HashSet` gives you linear time O(n) here, `TreeSet` n*logarithmic O(n*log n).

Comment: Not really, it depends on the quality of the underlying hashCode() implementation, if you have lot of collisions you will end up here in O(n^2). The correct O(n) approach is using sorted sets even though I am not sure that the retainAll API will do the correct approach in this case.

Comment: retainAll is just implemented in `AbstractCollection` which loops and removes. The algorithm you are looking for is not implemented in Java's SE, but C++ features it with `std::set_intersection`. Agree to the worst-case complexity in the `HashSet`, but we are talking about amortized complexity here and in the average case insert/lookup will perfom better than linear time.

Comment: Indeed I was looking for Collections#intersect but wasn't there, I was probably thinking about STL. Since we can't assume anything about the type of the underlying elements, I would simply stay on the safe side and use `SortedSet<T>` and implement the linear intersection myself.